# UPDATE table SET time = NOW() not working

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm very confused here, this is like lesson 1 mysql topic, but..

```
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET lastactivity = NOW() WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Why does this not update `lastactivity` from `usuarios` to `current_timestamp`?

```
lastactivity   timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: What is the data type of `lastactivity`?

Comment: Have you given $id any value?

Comment: TIMESTAMP, and no error messages... PLUS i have echo's debugging before and after, PLUS if i execute it in PHPMYADMIN as SQL sentence it says updated :S. @Richard, yes, it's debugged... :?

Comment: If your SQL statement is succesful from phpmyadmin, the problem must be something else. What about your database connection? Does it connect? Did you accidentally connect to the wrong database server, or to the wrong database? Since you do not get any error message, it looks like you're updating the wrong database, or you simply do not have a matching row in your table. Can you SELECT a row with id='$id' from your php script?

Comment: well it says updated but date stils 0000-00-00 00:00:00 :?

Comment: So the row was not updated, probably because it did not match your WHERE clause. Did you replace $id with the correct value? You can check with a SELECT-statement which rows match your WHERE clause: SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$id' where, of course, you have to replace $id.